# Xubuntu automatically renames whisker menu to its default "Applications Menu"

Tags: xubuntu, 20.04, xfce-panel

Whenever I rename the default name of Whisker Menu from "Application Menu" to something else, it reverts back to "Application Menu" after a reboot, or logout & login.

How to fix this?

[image]

I am using Xubuntu 20.04.

This has been reported as a [bug in Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin/+bug/1876336). Please mark "It affects me" if it does, as then the developers will give more importance to the bug report.

Comment: Hard to say what you mean, could you please add a screenshot to make it clearer?

Comment: @mook765 I have added screenshot.

Comment: Same behaviour for me, this looks like a bug. Whisker menu configuration should be stored in `~/.config/xfce4/panel/whiskermenu-1.rc`. But I cant find the panel button title in the file.

Comment: I can find a line `button-title=Applications Menu` in the configuration file when I create a fresh panel and add the Whisker menu to it. as soon as I edit the title this line is gone. This is definetely a bug.

Comment: @mook765 I have submitted a bug report here. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin/+bug/1876336 Please mark "It affects me". Should I submit another one in XFCE Bugzilla?

Comment: No, one bug report will be sufficient, a second bug-report will only produce duplicates. The launchpad team will forward the bug-report to the developers.

Comment: As a workaround: I found a file `/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntustudio/xfce4/whiskermenu/default.rc`, you can try to edit this file (needs root access). The file might be in a different folder on your system since you use Xubuntu while I use UbuntuStudio. I just searchd for `whiskermenu` in `/etc` to find the file.

Comment: We should close your question since it's a bug. I added myself as affected, bug is confirmed already.

Comment: Anyway, please post your last comment as an answer. Since the bug is not fixed yet, it should be here as an workaround.

Comment: Adding `button-title=New name` to `~/.config/xfce4/panel/whiskermenu-1.rc` works as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm this behaviour in UbuntuStudio 20.04.

Workaround until the bug is fixed:

I found a file `/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntustudio/xfce4/whiskermenu/default.rc`, you can try to edit this file (needs root access). The file might be in a different folder on your system since you use Xubuntu while I use UbuntuStudio. I just searched for `whiskermenu` in `/etc` to find the file.

For Xubuntu edit the file `/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu/xfce4/whiskermenu/defaults.rc`. One can also edit `~/.config/xfce4/panel/whiskermenu-1.rc`, which would not require root permissions.